# What commands does the Software Updater run?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates, update-manager

I was just wondering, what commands does the Software Updater run? Am I right in assuming that it runs something like?:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. It doesn't run these commands, but interfaces with the APT Python library. See [`UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/update-manager/wily/view/head:/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py#L58) in the source.